# How to create android shape background programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create this shape programmatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#e67e22"/> 
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

I've tried this simple function which gets corners, colors and sets that to shape:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_header);

    GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) linearLayout.getDrawable();

    float[] values = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f };
    drawable.setCornerRadii(values);
```

But I got this error:

**The method getDrawable() is undefined for the type LinearLayout**

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically)...

Comment: why not use multiple styles?

Comment: @Droidekas i must be have more than 20 style xml file if i can not create custom function to create that

Comment: Did you try using a custom view?

Comment: @Droidekas no sir, can you introducing any tutorials or helo me? by the way Post Updated

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100660/create-layer-list-with-rounded-corners-programmatically) if you are familiar with android programming

Comment: "The method getDrawable() is undefined for the type LinearLayout" Error Because in XML first, you need to define the background for that LinearLaout. Then only programmatically it able to fetch an override that drawable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've created a library which can help to create drawables programmatically.

See here: [DrawableToolbox](https://github.com/duanhong169/DrawableToolbox).

With `DrawableToolbox`, you can create it by:

```
Drawable drawable = new DrawableBuilder()
        .rectangle()
        .solidColor(0xffe67e22)
        .bottomLeftRadius(20) // in pixels
        .bottomRightRadius(20) // in pixels
//        .cornerRadii(0, 0, 20, 20) // the same as the two lines above
        .build();
```

Comment: this library hasn't had a commit since Sept 2018. And its only hosted on jcenter repo, which is deprecated. I recommend using GradientDrawable or another class that is part of the android sdk.

Answer (score 167):

You can do it like this:

```
public static void customView(View v, int backgroundColor, int borderColor) {
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
    v.setBackground(shape);
}
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setCornerRadii(float[])) for the meaning of `setCornerRadii` params.

You can use this function throughout your app and can put border and background color of your choice.

Comment: @AnkushJoshi, use setBackground

Answer (score 37):

If what you want is just a **simple rounded rectangle**, cut the long story short.

```
    float r=8; // the border radius in pixel
    ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable (new RoundRectShape(new float[] { r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r },null,null));
    shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    view.setBackground(shape);
```

---

- **What is the RoundRectShape ?**

`RoundRectShape` specifies an outer (*round*) rect and an optional inner (*round*) rect.

```
// RoundRectShape constructor

   RoundRectShape(float[] outerRadii,
                     RectF inset,
                   float[] innerRadii);
```

- ***outerRadii*** is an array of 8 radius values, for the outer roundrect.
  The first two floats are for the *top-left* corner (remaining pairs correspond clockwise). For no rounded corners on the outer rectangle, just pass ***null***.

[image]

For example:

[image]

- ***inset*** is a *RectF* that specifies the distance from the inner rect to each side of the outer rect. For no inner, pass ***null***.
- ***innerRadii*** is an array of 8 radius values, for the inner roundrect. The first two floats are for the top-left corner (remaining pairs correspond clockwise). For no rounded corners on the inner rectangle, pass ***null***. If inset parameter is ***null***, this parameter is ignored.

For example:

[image]

```
ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(
        new RoundRectShape(
            new float[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
            new RectF(10, 20, 10, 20),
            new float[]{40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40}));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `OVAL` shape instead of rectangle:

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
shape.setColor(Color.WHITE);
shape.setStroke(2, Color.BLACK);
view.setBackground(shape);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to Create

> Rounded drawable with Gradient

then use below code.

```
public static GradientDrawable generateGradientBackgroundCircular(String topColor, String bottomColor) {
    int[] colors = {Color.parseColor(topColor), Color.parseColor(bottomColor)};

    //create a new gradient color
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, colors);
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);

    return gd;
}
```