# How to apply rounded corner to a view based on its width in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, progress-bar

I am working on a custom Progress bar as photos below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically, I created a drawable xml background file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/jungleGreen"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then I applied it to the view that I am using:

```
<View
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar_placeholder_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_filled_patronage_progressbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

It is totally fine and I can achieve scenario 1 and 2, but when the bar is getting closer to the end, how can I programmatically set the rounded corner for the top right and the bottom right part of the view until it looks like in photo 3?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do it in raw XML, but you can always draw all 4 rounded corners and apply a clip (rectangle) to remove unwanted part of the drawable.

Comment: @Pawel can you be more specific? I know there is a way to draw the view's background but unsure how to change corners based on its width?

Comment: test something like this view.width - ((view.width)/(n))
change (n) to whatever u want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    public static void customView(View v, int backgroundColor, int borderColor)
 {
            GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
            shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
            shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
            shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
            v.setBackground(shape);
        }
```

Source : [How to create android shape background programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578701/how-to-create-android-shape-background-programmatically)

Comment: okay I think I understand how to do it now :) Thanks mate I will give it a try.

Comment: and if you need kotlin version i can help you with it.

Comment: Tried it and it works fine for me, I converted it to Kotlin and posted it below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Madhav's solution works for me, so basically I will need to pass in the width of the view, then calculate the corner radius number and put it into gradientDrawable as below:

```
    private fun setupGraphBackground(view: View, graphWidth: Int) {
            val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable()
            gradientDrawable.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
            gradientDrawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.jungleGreen))
            gradientDrawable.setStroke(0, null)
            gradientDrawable.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(45f, 45f, 
                graphWidth * calculationRules, graphWidth * calculationRules, 
                graphWidth * calculationRules, graphWidth * calculationRules, 
                45f, 45f)
            view.background = gradientDrawable
        }
```

Where as calculationRules is the rule I want so that I can get the right radius of the topRight and bottomRight corner.