# Change frame of outlined button

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have list of outlined button:
[image]

I set a selector as a background of button.
How can I change the color of stroke programmatically? For example:
Now:
[image]

And after click on Button it has to became next:

[image]

I don't think I need to create a selectors for every color. I think, I could get a color of stroke programmatically. Please give me a hint!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is create a `drawable` by programmatically, you can check it here: [How to create android shape background programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578701/how-to-create-android-shape-background-programmatically)

Comment: Ok, but if, I don't want to create new drawable, how to get access to current drawable?

Comment: @JekisOsipov Try this: `Drawable clone = drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable();`

Comment: What's about this method for Kotlin? I could not find getConstantState. Thanks

Comment: For Kotlin, let's use `gettet/setter`, ex: `drawable.constantState`